# Mistake in abbot convergence of sequence of functions?

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation

I am currently self-studying real analysis from Abbot. I am just wondering here as $n \longrightarrow \infty$  shouldn't $h(x) = x$ why is it here $|x|$ ?[image]

Comment: Try it for $x=-1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{align*}
&\;\text{For fixed $x \in [-1,1]$,}\\[6pt]
&\lim_{n \to \infty}x^{1+\frac{1}{2n-1}}\\[4pt]
=\;&\lim_{n \to \infty}x^{\frac{2n}{2n-1}}\\[4pt]
=\;&\lim_{n \to \infty}(x^2)^{\frac{n}{2n-1}}\\[4pt]
=\;&\lim_{n \to \infty}(|x|^2)^{\frac{n}{2n-1}}\\[4pt]
=\;&\lim_{n \to \infty}(|x|)^{\frac{2n}{2n-1}}\\[4pt]
=\;&\lim_{n \to \infty}(|x|)^{1}\\[4pt]
=\;&\lim_{n \to \infty}|x|\\[4pt]
=\;&|x|\\[12pt]
&\;\text{Alternatively, using the author's approach,}\\[6pt] 
&\lim_{n \to \infty}x^{1+\frac{1}{2n-1}}\\[4pt]
=\;&x\lim_{n \to \infty}x^{\frac{1}{2n-1}}\\[4pt]
=\;&x\bigl(\text{sgn}(x)\bigr)\qquad\text{[since odd roots retain the sign of the input]}\\[4pt]
=\;&|x|\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
where $\text{sgn}(x)$ is the function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ defined by
$$
\text{sgn}(x) =
\begin{cases}
-1&\text{if}\;x<0
\\[4pt]
0&\text{if}\;x=0\\[4pt]
1&\text{if}\;x>0\\[4pt]
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: how did you get that $x^{\frac{1}{2n - 1}} = sgn(x)$

Comment: For nonzero $x \in [-1,1]$, the expression $|x|^{\frac{1}{2n-1}}$ approaches $1$, as $n$ approaches infinity, but since we are taking _odd_ roots, the sign is retained. In the context of this problem, we are assuming $n$ is a positive integer.

Comment: oh sure okay yeah I understand this.